# Backup/sync Mac photo to external hard drive

Tags: mac, backup, photos, photos.app, external-disk

It's already making me crazy - as a newbie with Mac. I have problem with backup/sync of my pictures.
I would like to backup pictures from *Photo* library (Photo app) to external *HDD* but more like sync.

- All the **new pictures** in my Mac should be **copied to external HDD**.
- **Pictures that are already on external HDD** should **NOT be copied there twice** (not classic backup of whole library).
- Pictures **I erased from Mac** should **NOT be erased from external HDD** (not classic sync).
- If import of new pictures would be **automatic** when external *HDD* is connected it would be great (not manually copying new pictures).

Is that possible with Mac? With Windows I used to do just **import new pictures to external HDD library**. It never deletes any picture from external *HDD* even I delete it from my *PC* library.

Comment: Have you thought about putting your Photo library on the external HDD?

Comment: I don't have external HDD all the time connected to my Mac. Also if I just copy Photo library to External HDD, than I don't know what to do with new pictures. If I would copy Photo library again (with some pitures deleted and some new pictures) and replaced that old copy than I would  loose that erased pictures even on external HDD. If I would keep even that old library, than I would have a lot of pictures on external HDD twice. So, that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you copy it over an over, I suggest you may have a permanent external library where you put your pictures, just as you describe you did before on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a sync/backup tool like [ChronoSync](http://www.econtechnologies.com/) (which I highly recommend)? It can be scheduled to sync to when your external drive is mounted. It also does a great job of handling package files (which is what your iPhoto library is). It's from Econ Technologies and can be trialed for 30 days.